# How to find values of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MusXB.jpg)So i have the system of equations as attached on the image above. I want to find the values of k for which the system is consistent.

I put it in the form of an augmented matrix to get

1 1 -1 2

1 1 0 1

1 1 k 0

And if now i put it in row echelon form , i get

1 1 -1 2

0 0 1 -1

0 0 0 1

The k disappears. The system is inconsistent in the last row because z(=0)=1, which is impossible. However,  I want to find the values of k for which the system is consistent! How do i do that ?

Comment: In the future, please take the time to enter important parts of your question—such as the homework problem that you’re solving—as text instead of pasting a picture of it. Images are neither searchable nor accessible to people using screen readers. Moreover, you’re forcing anyone who might want to help you to open a link instead of being able to read your entire question in one place. You can find a quick reference for formatting mathematical expressions using MathJax [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how you got that row echelon form, but note that it follows from the second equation that $x+y=1$. So, the first and the third equations become $-z=1$ and $kz=-1$. Obviously, there's one and only one $k$ for which this system is consistent.

Comment: sorry, didn't understand your process. I did the REF with my ti nspire calculator, so i think its correct. Then the x would be equal to 3-y from (x+y-z=2) where from the second row z=-1.

Comment: I still don't get how to solve for k

Comment: The only way that the system$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}-z=1\\kz=-1\end{array}\right.$$is consistent is to take $k=1$. Otherwise, you get two distinct values for $z$.

Comment: How do you get there? Can you please show me the steps?

Comment: It seems to me quite weird that something like that is worth 6 marks in an exam of 30 marks...

Comment: @MichaelMorello I solve the first equation, getting $z=-1$. Then I plunge it in the second equation, getting $-k=-1$, which is equivalent to $k=1$.

Comment: Second equation ? K is only in the third equation ....

Comment: @MichaelMorello I meant the second equation of my previous comment.

Comment: I am just really confused at this point

Comment: Why is -k=-1? if i plug z, which is equal to -1, into kz, i get -k.

Comment: Okay . i got why -k=-1 . Now the thing i don't get is how to show for what systems k is consistent.

Comment: How do i find the values for k for which the system is consistent? i got k =1. But what does that mean ?

Comment: It means that it is consistent when (and only when) $k=1$.

Comment: Okay thanks... last thing, i often tend to use the row echelon form to find values of k for which the system is consistent, when there is more than 1 k in the three equations.. so how come i have to use this other method to find the k consistency ? I always used row echelon form ....

Comment: @MichaelMorello I never claimed that you **had** to use this method. It just seemed much simpler in this specific situation. And if my answer was useful, perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.

Comment: yes indeed i will , very useful thanks so much

Comment: Do you think i could solve this using row echelon form ?

Comment: How would i do that ?

Comment: @MichaelMorello You should have got$$\begin{pmatrix}1&1&-1&2\\0&0&1&-1\\0&0&0&k-1\end{pmatrix}.$$The last line corresponds to the equation $0=k-1$, and therefore the system is consistent if and only if $k=1$ (again).

Comment: Okay , i am thinking that i could still do something with my row echelon form where i also get that z= -1

Comment: One last thing, where did you get the second equation kz=-1?

Comment: 1) i do k times -1 which gives me -k. How do i proceed from there ?

Comment: @MichaelMorello This is another question. Please post it as such.

Comment: couldn't you tell me?

Comment: @MichaelMorello See what I've written so far. Don't you think that I've already helped you a lot?

Comment: Yes indeed. I just really didn't get how to continue when i found z=-1 and why kz=-1. That's all

Comment: because plugging in z=-1 into the third equation ,( taking into consideration that x+y=1) , 1+(-k)=0 from which i then i get 1-k=0, and that k equals 1

Comment: So i would indeed say that the system is consistent only when k is NOT equal to 1