# Finding values of a matrix to make it consistent

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

> Determine the values of $k \in \mathbb{R}$ so that the following system
> $$
> \left\{\begin{aligned}
> x+y-z &=2 \\
> x+y &=1 \\
> x+y+k z &=0
> \end{aligned}\right.
> $$
> consistent and compute the solution.

So I have a system of linear equations as seen on the image I attached up here.

$x+y-z=2$

$x+y=1$

$x+y+kz=0$

I want to find the values of $k$ in order to make the system consistent. As the question asks.

I was thinking , as $x+y=1$, to plug this in the first equation and get $z=-1$. Then I plug the $z=-1$ into the third equation to get $k =1$. So is the system consistent as long as $k$ is not equal to $1$?

Can somebody please help me ?

Comment: You're perfectly correct.

Comment: Do you mean "the system is consistent as long as $k$ **is** equal to $1$?

Comment: No , i mean if it is consistent as long as k is not equal to 1. Actually , i don't really understand in this case where the system is consistent or not, meaning i'm not sure if the system is consistent when k=1 or when it is NOT equal to 1... can you please explain ? Thanks!

Comment: okay, I'll write an answer.

Comment: How is this different from [your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2822649/265466) about this same exercise?

Comment: I coulnd't understand it in the previous question !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The system is consistent as long as $k$ **is** equal to $1$. When $k = 1$, the equations admit solutions. In fact, the equations admit an infinite family of solutions: any $(x, y, z)$ with $x + y = 1$ and $z = -1$ is a solution, i.e. the set of solutions when $k = 1$ is the set $\{(t, 1 - t, -1) : t \in \mathbb R \}$, which looks like a straight line in $\mathbb R^3$.

When $k \neq 1$, the equations are inconsistent, and have no solutions. Indeed, the first two equations tell us that $x + y = 1$ and $z = -1$, which implies that $x + y + kz = 1 - k$. But the third equation states that $x + y + kz = 0$. The conclusion is that the third equation cannot possibly be satisfied while the first two equations are satisfied if $k \neq 1$.

Comment: THANKS!!! why is x+y+kz=1−k???

Comment: I really appreciate your answer, but i still don't get the hand of it... unfortunately. For example, if k=2, the last equation would then be x+y+2z=0, how can that be inconsistent?

Comment: @MichaelMorello I was saying that the first two equations imply $x + y = 1$ and $z = -1$, and that this would then imply that $x + y + kz = (x + y) + k(z) = 1 + k(-1) = 1 - k$.

Comment: @MichaelMorello Suppose $k = 2$. From my comment above, the first two equations tells you that $x + y + 2z = 1 - 2 = -1$. This contradicts the third equation, which says that $x + y + 2z = 0$.

Comment: So practiically , we WANT the third equation , which is 1-k to equal 0 ? correct?

Comment: Because if we had k=2, then 1-k would NOT be equal to 0

Comment: @MichaelMorello If we had $k = 2$, then it would be impossible to come up with an $(x,y,z)$ that satisfy all three equations. For any $(x, y, z)$ that satisfies the first two equations, we would have $x + y + 2z = -1$. For any $(x,y,z)$ that satisfies the third equation, we would have $x + y + 2z = 0$. So it is impossible to find any $(x,y,z)$ that satisfies all three equations simultaneously.

Comment: Okay perfect, thanks! Then the solutions of this system would be : z=-1, x=1-y and y=1-x, right?

Comment: In the case where $k = 1$, there are many infinitely solutions to this system: for example, $(x,y,z)=(0,1,-1)$ is a solution, and $(x,y,z)=(\tfrac 1 2, \tfrac 1 2 , -1)$ is a solution, and $(x,y,z) = (1, 0, -1)$ is a solution, and $(x,y,z) = (1234, -1233, -1)$, and there are many others! On the other hand, in the case where $k = 2$, there are no solutions, because you can't find any $(x,y,z)$ that fits all three equations simultaneously when $k = 2$.

Answer (score 0):

The key word here is "simultaneously." For the linear system to be consistent, all three of the equations must be satisfied simultaneously for at least one fixed triplet $(x,y,z)$. That is, there must be at least one set of values $x = a, y = b, z = c, (a, b,$ and $c$ real numbers), for which ALL of the equations hold. By choosing $k = 1$, we guarantee this is the case.

Comment: Thanks ! Great explanation

Comment: But i have a question , on my previous excerices on matrices i saw that the systems are inconsistent when , in the last row of the matrices, the third entry is equal to zero, and the entry after that (supposing there are 4 entries in a row) is equal to a number. So i thought that my system would be inconsistent when k is not equal to 1 , because if 1-1=0, the fourth entry is also zero and then there would be 0=0